# Need help with IP Tables rule to filter by Hex

Tags: networking, server, security, iptables

I'm setting up a server and I need to make an specific configuration. I have to drop an specific packet which always starts with `XX 01`. I can do this, with this rule:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport XXXX -m string --hex-string '|XX 01|' --algo bm -j REJECT
```

But the problem is that `iptables` starts reading from the first HEX character, so, sometimes it generates false positives.
I mean, `iptables` drops good packets that matches with the rule.For example: it drops `aa aa aa XX 01 aa aa aa aa`.

What I need `iptables` to do, is to only discard the packet ONLY if `XX 01` is the first 4 characters of the data string. Ignoring if it's present after the 4th data. I mean, if I have for example `6D 00 00 00 00 00 XX 01 00 AA` it has to pass.

I know there is the opposite way to do it, I mean, I can just connect my server and sniff incoming packets with `wireshark`, in order to whitelist the first Hex that's not `XX 01` for every packet which contains `XX 01` on it's data string: for example the `6D` string I put up there. But for doing it that way I need to sniff for hours and I have to create like a lot of rules. I need to set up a rule to whitelist all the packets which start with anything but `XX 01`, or a rule which stops reading the packet after the 4th Hex character.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont know if the pattern matching is regex (it should be), but if it is, try using ^XX 01 .. the circumflex (^) means start of line, so that should match anything that _starts_ with XX 01.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `string` section of the `iptables-extensions` manual page, there are two options for controlling which part of a packet the pattern is tested against:

```
   --from offset
          Set the offset from which it starts looking for any matching. If
          not passed, default is 0.

   --to offset
          Set the offset up to which should be scanned. That is, byte off‐
          set-1 (counting from 0) is the last one that is scanned.  If not
          passed, default is the packet size.
```

Have you tried `--to 2` argument, which supposedly should limit matching range length to that value?